# If statement returning wrong files for Google sheet function

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Using a function that that will assign `TRUE` if a value is over `0` or `FALSE` if not. The point of this function is to work with the true values for a script.

```
=IF(H2 > 0, TRUE)
```

It doesn't make any sense because some blank cells say `TRUE` and some blank cells say `FALSE`. I'm not sure what would cause this.

Comment: Specify that the conditions shall only be fulfilled for numbers: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1), A1 > 0), TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your cells containing numbers e.g. cell `H2` are **correctly formatted as numbers and not as text**.

You can check that by using the `ISNUMBER` function

[image]